# Flink application running in kubernetes failing with ProducerFencedException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, kafka-producer-api

I have a flink application where I am setting `execution.checkpointing.mode='EXACTLY_ONCE'` and then I have a KafkaSink with the following setup

```
KafkaSink<KafkaSinkEvent> sink =
                KafkaSink.<KafkaSinkEvent>builder()
                        .setBootstrapServers(config.getKafka().getHost())
                        .setRecordSerializer(KafkaRecordSerializationSchema.<KafkaSinkEvent>builder()
                                .setTopic("topic-name")
                                .setValueSerializationSchema(new KafkaSinkEventSerializationSchema())
                                .build())
                        .setKafkaProducerConfig(toProperties(config.getKafka().getProducerConfig()))
                        .setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.EXACTLY_ONCE)
                        .setTransactionalIdPrefix("AppNameKafkaSink")
                        .build();
```

In `toProperties` I am just setting `transactions.timeout.ms` = 1000

The job is running in a kubernetes cluster with 3 pods and parallelism of the application is 3.

I am getting error `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one.`

Does anyone have any suggestion on how this issue can be resolved?

I tried providing an UUID to `transactionalId` but that faces the same issue.